# ApiController not returning result to $http.post() request

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller in my angularJS,

```
    var user = {
        Username: $scope.username,
        Password: $scope.password
    };


    var promisePost = loginService.post(user);
    promisePost.then(function (result) {
        var res = result.data;
        //TODO: set permissions
    },
```

This links to a service,

```
this.post = function (user) {
    return $http.post(toApiUrl('login'), user);
}
```

And then in my API controller I have the following,

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(UserLogin user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the specified credentials
            var validationResult = this.ValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password);
            if (validationResult.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
                return Ok();
            }
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

My issue is that it never returns to the var res = result.data in my javascript. If I make my api method completely empty (and change it to void) then it will reach that line in the debugger, so something is going wrong in this API method. It is reaching the actual return Ok line, just not then going back properly. Any ideas.?

Comment: Just to note, I would recommend you take a look at ngResource instead, since that wraps requests to api:s so you don't need to do the http yourself

Comment: Do you see anything in your browser console? Can you look at the network tab in your browser and see what you receive from the post request?

Comment: Also, when asking questions, there's no need for writing "tag1:tag2:title", there's [a system in place for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/147072)

Comment: I checked the network tab and noticed that the correct results were actually being returned, so put some alert boxes in and they are being activated correctly. Not sure why my break points were not working correctly.

Comment: You can try to write `debugger;` in your JavaScript code which will break if the browser debugger is up.